# How do you send an UDP package to an controller?

Tags: c#, sockets, controller, udp, sdn

I can't find anything about sending an UDP command to any controller. How can I make that package understandable for the controller. Don't blame me guys I don't know anything about sdn controllers or UDP sending messages. Actually I tried to send just text with UDP command, that worked! But I need to send a real package and connect that package to my sdn controller.

Any help?

Comment: Start by studying the (documentation of the) protocol(s) your SDN is using and the documentation of the controller itself. If you don't know which protocols your SDN is using, nor what controller(s) are used in the SDN, how should we know? ;-)

Comment: There is no difference in sending Text and sending commands.  Commands are just text.  You need to create an application that sends commands and then waits for the responses.